# Singleton with Arguments in Java

Tags: java, oop, singleton, anti-patterns

I was reading the Singleton article on Wikipedia and I came across this example:

```
public class Singleton {
    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() {}

    /**
     * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
     * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
     */
    private static class SingletonHolder { 
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

While I really like the way this Singleton behaves, I can't see how to adapt it to incorporate arguments to the constructor.  What is the preferred way to do this in Java?  Would I have to do something like this?

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton singleton = null;  
    private final int x;

    private Singleton(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public synchronized static Singleton getInstance(int x) {
        if(singleton == null) singleton = new Singleton(x);
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

---

Edit:  I think I have started a storm of controversy with my desire to use Singleton.  Let me explain my motivation and hopefully someone can suggest a better idea.  I am using a grid computing framework to execute tasks in parallel.  In general, I have something like this:

```
// AbstractTask implements Serializable
public class Task extends AbstractTask
{
    private final ReferenceToReallyBigObject object;

    public Task(ReferenceToReallyBigObject object)
    {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // Do some stuff with the object (which is immutable).
    }
}
```

What happens is that even though I merely pass a reference to my data to all of the tasks, when the tasks are serialized, the data gets copied over and over.  What I want to do is share the object among all of the tasks.  Naturally, I might modify the class like so:

```
// AbstractTask implements Serializable
public class Task extends AbstractTask
{
    private static ReferenceToReallyBigObject object = null;

    private final String filePath;

    public Task(String filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            if(object == null)
            {
                ObjectReader reader = new ObjectReader(filePath);
                object = reader.read();
            }
        }

        // Do some stuff with the object (which is immutable).
    }
}
```

As you can see, even here I have the issue that passing a different file path means nothing after the first one is passed.  This is why I like the idea for a *store* which was posted in the answers.  Anyhow, rather than including the logic for loading the file in the run method, I wanted to abstract this logic into a Singleton class.  I will not provide yet another example, but I hope you get the idea.  Please let me hear your ideas for a more elegant way to accomplish what I am trying to do.  Thank you again!

Comment: The factory pattern is what you want. Ideally, grid tasks should be completely independent of anything else and get sent all the data they need to execute and return their results. However, this is not always the most feasible solution, so serializing the data to a file is not so bad an idea. I think the whole singleton thing is a bit of a red-herring; you don't want a singleton.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that you used the term Singleton that comes with such a baggage. The proper term for this pattern is Interning actually. Interning is a method to ensure that abstract values are represented by one instance only. String interning is the most common usage: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool .

Comment: You may want to have a look at Terracotta. It maintains object identity across the cluster. When you send a reference to data already in the cluster it doesn't get re-serialized.

Comment: Putting aside the issue of whether the singleton pattern should ever be used, I'd note that almost every answer here seems to assume that the purpose of providing an argument is to allow for "multiple singletons" to be created that are distinguished by the value of said parameter.  But another possible purpose is to provide *access* to an external object that is the *only* object of its kind that the  singleton class' *unique* instance will ever need.  So we need to distinguish a parameter provided for such access from a parameter intended to create "multiple singleton instances."

Comment: Another scenario for a "singleton with parameters": a web application that will build its unique immutable singleton based on the informations coming with the very first upcoming request (thread). The domain of the request could determine some singleton's behaviour for example

Comment: I have a different requirement, as I want to have a unique instance for each given argument.

Answer (score 204):

I'll make my point very clear: **a singleton with parameters is not a singleton**.

A singleton, by definition, is an object you want to be instantiated no more than once. If you are trying to feed parameters to the constructor, what is the point of the singleton?

You have two options. If you want your singleton to be initialized with some data, you may load it with data *after instantiation*, like so:

```
SingletonObj singleton = SingletonObj.getInstance();
singleton.init(paramA, paramB); // init the object with data
```

If the operation your singleton is performing is recurring, and with different parameters every time, you might as well pass the parameters to the main method being executed:

```
SingletonObj singleton = SingletonObj.getInstance();
singleton.doSomething(paramA, paramB); // pass parameters on execution
```

In any case, instantiation will always be parameter-less. Otherwise your singleton is not a singleton.

Comment: +1 This is how I'd probably do it when coding. In C#, I'd just use properties though. Java, probably like this.

Comment: sorry, thats not true. there are situations where you have to pass in dynamicly created parameters which stay the same for the hole application runtime. so you cant use a constant within the singleton but have to pass that constant when its created. after passed once its the same constant for the hole time. a setter wont do the job if you need that specific constant within the constructor.

Comment: @masi, as author says - it's not a singleton. If you need to pass constant dynamicaly, you may need create a lot of such classes with different constants. So, there is no point in singleton.

Comment: The first two lines of code are implicitly using "getInstance()" to mean "create the singleton object." So this getInstance() call is different from any other, as you have to ensure that this is the first getInstance() call, and the creation of the instance now depends upon external code that is known (by the programmer) to call getInstance() first.  An alternative would be to explicitly create just one instance of the (now non-singleton) object, passing the arguments in the constructor, and create a static method to access it at the application level (or just pass it directly to clients).

Comment: Also, if the internal constructor used by getInstance() when it is called the first time requires access to the parameters (e.g., to pass to the constructor of a class from which the singleton class is derived), this won't work because the parameters are not supplied until after that constructor has been executed.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a static method called createInitialInstance(paramA, paramB), that must be called prior to any call to getInstance(), in which case getInstance() would be a simple accessor that does not create the object instance (with an assert to test that the instance is not null).

Comment: It would seem that the only static method/property that need exist is the getInstance() method.  That method/property returns the object.  Then, an Init() method which uses a boolean to prevent multiple initializations: `void Init(object[] params) { if(!initialized) { /* do init */ } }`

Comment: If you only need one instance of a class for an application's entire lifetime, but you need to provide that instance with a value at launch time, why is this no longer a singleton?

Comment: @YuvalAdam i was searching for "Singleton with parameter" on google and so i came here. I wanted to use Singleton with parameters (i found a solution without singleton) for my A* path finding. I have a level grid and a few enemies moving arround, looking for the player with A*. For this i wanted to create the Singelton instance with the map as parameter to instantiate it only once, as the map is the same for every enemie. Why wouldn't that be a Singelton anymore?

Comment: I strongly disagree with your opening sentence due to the C-word : CONTEXT

Comment: An example against your assumption is the database helper class in android. The best practice would be to have a singleton for this class to maintain just one connection to database, but it expects a parameter(`Context`) for the same.

Comment: "If you are trying to feed parameters to the constructor, what is the point of the singleton?" - One could also say: "If you make your whole application single instance, what is the point of command line arguments?", and the answer is that it makes a lot of sense. One could now say that this is fairly different from a singleton class, except if the class is actually the Main class that does receive the args[] from the main method - then it's even the same thing. The final argument, which might just stand, is that this is a fairly exceptional situation.

Comment: If a Singleton class need to be initialized before using it then the client(which class are going to use it) will never know if the Singleton has yet been initialized or not. And also the client could not have the right properties to initialized the Singleton.

Comment: For me patterns are just a guide to follow. Follow this rules strictly, for the sake of calling the implemented structure a "singleton", it's just stupid.

Comment: "**A singleton with parameters is not a singleton**" -> Singleton pattern: 1) `Ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists` 2) `Provide global access to that instance`. No mention at all about parameters. And yes there are situations where we need to set dynamically parameters (For example in inheritance cases to force the singleton to set some superclass properties).

Comment: ++ @AmanDeepGautam your question still remains unanswered. Yes I want to create a singleton with some configuration instead of passing that config each time I call any of its methods. --YuvalAdam: Enough with this parroting of the "patterns" - A Monty Pythons for computer programming bureaucracy is urgently needed.

Comment: I understand the point, for the rest not agreeing, the issue is: if getInstance() has a parameter, then any class using the "singleton" should pass that parameter, which is not what you want in general. Also if we talk about "singleton" as the design pattern, it is not designer with parameters, so with parameters doesn't comply with the definition of singleton. Though you can still implement whatever you want, that doesn't make it strictly correct or compliant with the design pattern.

Comment: Disagree, I have a singleton that receives its argument from a command-line argument.

Comment: This answer needs more downvotes. For example when you need a spring-like singleton scoped beans with another bean injected within - it's not an anti-pattern but a normal use case.

Answer (score 44):

I think you need something like a **factory** to have objects with various parameters instantiated and reused. It could be implemented by using a synchronized `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` map a parameter (an `Integer` for an example) to your 'singleton' parameterizable class.

Although you might get to the point where you should use regular, non-singleton classes instead (for example needing 10.000 differently parametrized singleton).

Here is an example for such store:

```
public final class UsefulObjFactory {

    private static Map<Integer, UsefulObj> store =
        new HashMap<Integer, UsefulObj>();

    public static final class UsefulObj {
        private UsefulObj(int parameter) {
            // init
        }
        public void someUsefulMethod() {
            // some useful operation
        }
    }

    public static UsefulObj get(int parameter) {
        synchronized (store) {
            UsefulObj result = store.get(parameter);
            if (result == null) {
                result = new UsefulObj(parameter);
                store.put(parameter, result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

To push it even further, the Java `enum`s can be also considered (or used as) parametrized singletons, although allowing only a fixed number static variants.

However, if you need a distributed<sup>1</sup> solution, consider some lateral caching solution. For example: EHCache, Terracotta, etc.

<sup>1</sup> in the sense of spanning multiple VMs on probably multiple computers.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need.  Thank you very much!  I agree that the way I was handling arguments in my example didn't make much sense, but I didn't think of this.  See my explanation in the comments of oxbow_lakes' answer.

Comment: This is **NOT** a singleton; you now have more than one of them. LOL

Comment: @Scott: I'd suggest something like what Yuval suggested below. It makes a little more sense and you have a 'true' singleton. [edit]

Comment: I hope no-one minds me editing the names in the code; I can imagine this is really confusing for newbies. Rollback if you disagree

Comment: Yes, we could call them Multitron and still achieve the same goal the OP wanted in the first place IMHO.

Comment: Please no-one suggest that anyone should be using terracotta unless *they really know what they are doing**!

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: maybe its time to ask for integrated refactoring support of the editor :). And for the Terracotta - just wanted to list some options based on OP's comment in your answer.

Comment: I give up. No cognitive energy left for the modified question.

Comment: @Zack: Yuval's solution wont work in my case, because it fails to abstract the logic I was initially trying to remove from the run method.  If I used Yuval's Singleton, I would have something like this:

synchronized(this)
{
    if(!singleton.isInitialized())
        singleton.init(param);
}

Comment: @kd304: I was trying to spare the details, but people really hate Singleton. :-)  I guess I was a bit dishonest as well since what I really needed wasn't technically a Singleton, as oxbow_lakes and many others have pointed out.

Answer (score 42):

You can add a configurable initialization method in order to separate instantiation from getting.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton = null;
    private final int x;

    private Singleton(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(singleton == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("You have to call init first");
        }

        return singleton;
    }

    public synchronized static Singleton init(int x) {
        if (singleton != null)
        {
            // in my opinion this is optional, but for the purists it ensures
            // that you only ever get the same instance when you call getInstance
            throw new AssertionError("You already initialized me");
        }

        singleton = new Singleton(x);
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

Then you can call `Singleton.init(123)` once to configure it, for example in your app startup.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the Builder pattern if you want to show that some parameters are mandatory.

```
    public enum EnumSingleton {

    INSTANCE;

    private String name; // Mandatory
    private Double age = null; // Not Mandatory

    private void build(SingletonBuilder builder) {
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.age = builder.age;
    }

    // Static getter
    public static EnumSingleton getSingleton() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Name "+name + ", age: "+age);
    }


    public static class SingletonBuilder {

        private final String name; // Mandatory
        private Double age = null; // Not Mandatory

        private SingletonBuilder(){
          name = null;
        }

        SingletonBuilder(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public SingletonBuilder age(double age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public void build(){
            EnumSingleton.INSTANCE.build(this);
        }

    }


}
```

Then you could *create/instantiate/parametrized* it as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new EnumSingleton.SingletonBuilder("nico").age(41).build();
    EnumSingleton.getSingleton().print();
}
```

Comment: This is elegant.

Answer (score 12):

Surprised that no one mentioned how a logger is created/retrieved. For example, below shows how [Log4J logger](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/Logger.java#Logger.getLogger%28java.lang.String%29) is retrieved.

```
// Retrieve a logger named according to the value of the name parameter. If the named logger already exists, then the existing instance will be returned. Otherwise, a new instance is created.
public static Logger getLogger(String name)
```

There are some levels of indirections, but the key part is below [method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.eventtracker/3.1.0/org/apache/log4j/Hierarchy.java?av=h#259) which pretty much tells everything about how it works. It uses a hash table to store the exiting loggers and the key is derived from name. If the logger doesn't exist for a give name, it uses a factory to create the logger and then adds it to the hash table.

```
69   Hashtable ht;
...
258  public
259  Logger getLogger(String name, LoggerFactory factory) {
260    //System.out.println("getInstance("+name+") called.");
261    CategoryKey key = new CategoryKey(name);
262    // Synchronize to prevent write conflicts. Read conflicts (in
263    // getChainedLevel method) are possible only if variable
264    // assignments are non-atomic.
265    Logger logger;
266
267    synchronized(ht) {
268      Object o = ht.get(key);
269      if(o == null) {
270        logger = factory.makeNewLoggerInstance(name);
271        logger.setHierarchy(this);
272        ht.put(key, logger);
273        updateParents(logger);
274        return logger;
275      } else if(o instanceof Logger) {
276        return (Logger) o;
277      } 
...
```

Answer (score 6):

"**A singleton with parameters is not a singleton**" statement is **not completely correct**. We need to analyze this from the application perspective rather than from the code perspective.

We build singleton class to create a single instance of an object in one application run. By having a constructor with parameter, you can build flexibility into your code to change some attributes of your singleton object every time you run you application. This is not a violation of Singleton pattern. It looks like a violation if you see this from code perspective.

Design Patterns are there to help us write flexible and extendable code, not to hinder us writing good code.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP question, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use getters and setters to set the variable and make the default constructor private. Then use:

```
Singleton.getInstance().setX(value);
```

Comment: Don't get why this was down-voted.. It's a valid answer tbh. :/

Comment: Because it is a rubbish answer. For example, imagine a system where the initial username and password for the initial admin are constructor arguments. Now, if I make this a singleton and do as you say, I get getters and setters for the admin, which is not quite what you want. So while your option may be valid in some cases, it doesn't really answer the general case that was the question. (yes, I am working on the system I described and no, I wouldn't have use a singleton pattern if it wasn't for the fact that the assignment says "use a singleton pattern here")

Answer (score 4):

Modification of Singleton pattern that uses [Bill Pugh's initialization on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). This is thread safe without the overhead of specialized language constructs (i.e. volatile or synchronized):

```
public final class RInterfaceHL {

    /**
     * Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes.
     */
    private RInterfaceHL() { }

    /**
     * R REPL (read-evaluate-parse loop) handler.
     */
    private static RMainLoopCallbacks rloopHandler = null;

    /**
     * SingletonHolder is loaded, and the static initializer executed, 
     * on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() or the first 
     * access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
     */
    private static final class SingletonHolder {

        /**
         * Singleton instance, with static initializer.
         */
        private static final RInterfaceHL INSTANCE = initRInterfaceHL();

        /**
         * Initialize RInterfaceHL singleton instance using rLoopHandler from
         * outer class.
         * 
         * @return RInterfaceHL instance
         */
        private static RInterfaceHL initRInterfaceHL() {
            try {
                return new RInterfaceHL(rloopHandler);
            } catch (REngineException e) {
                // a static initializer cannot throw exceptions
                // but it can throw an ExceptionInInitializerError
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Prevent instantiation.
         */
        private SingletonHolder() {
        }

        /**
         * Get singleton RInterfaceHL.
         * 
         * @return RInterfaceHL singleton.
         */
        public static RInterfaceHL getInstance() {
            return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Return the singleton instance of RInterfaceHL. Only the first call to
     * this will establish the rloopHandler.
     * 
     * @param rloopHandler
     *            R REPL handler supplied by client.
     * @return RInterfaceHL singleton instance
     * @throws REngineException
     *             if REngine cannot be created
     */
    public static RInterfaceHL getInstance(RMainLoopCallbacks rloopHandler)
            throws REngineException {
        RInterfaceHL.rloopHandler = rloopHandler;

        RInterfaceHL instance = null;

        try {
            instance = SingletonHolder.getInstance();
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {

            // rethrow exception that occurred in the initializer
            // so our caller can deal with it
            Throwable exceptionInInit = e.getCause();
            throw new REngineException(null, exceptionInInit.getMessage());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * org.rosuda.REngine.REngine high level R interface.
     */
    private REngine rosudaEngine = null;

    /**
     * Construct new RInterfaceHL. Only ever gets called once by
     * {@link SingletonHolder.initRInterfaceHL}.
     * 
     * @param rloopHandler
     *            R REPL handler supplied by client.
     * @throws REngineException
     *             if R cannot be loaded.
     */
    private RInterfaceHL(RMainLoopCallbacks rloopHandler)
            throws REngineException {

        // tell Rengine code not to die if it can't
        // load the JRI native DLLs. This allows
        // us to catch the UnsatisfiedLinkError
        // ourselves
        System.setProperty("jri.ignore.ule", "yes");

        rosudaEngine = new JRIEngine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, rloopHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would it be a good idea to `finally { RInterfaceHL.rloopHandler = null; }` in `getInstance`, because that static reference may cause a memory leak if we're not careful. In your case it looks like it's not an issue, but I could imagine a scenario where the passed-in object is big and only used by `RInterfaceHL` ctor to get some values, and not to keep a reference to it.

Comment: Idea: `return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE` would work just as fine in `getInstance`. I don't think there's a need for encapsulation here, because the outer class already knows the innards of the inner class, they're tightly coupled: it knows `rloopHandler` needs init before calling. Also the private constructor has no effect, because the inner class' private stuff is simply available to the outer class.

Comment: Link is broken. Were you refering to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a Singleton class serving as a Context, a good way is to have a configuration file and read the parameters from the file inside instance().

If the parameters feeding the Singleton class are got dynamically during the running of your program, simply use a static HashMap storing different instances in your Singleton class to ensure that for each parameter(s), only one instance is created.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't make sense of how to accomplish what you're trying to do is probably that what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense.  You want to call `getInstance(x)` with different arguments, but always return the same object?  What behavior is it you want when you call `getInstance(2)` and then `getInstance(5)`?

If you want the same object but for its internal value to be different, which is the only way it's still a singleton, then you don't need to care about the constructor at all; you just set the value in `getInstance()` on the object's way out.  Of course, you understand that all your other references to the singleton now have a different internal value.

If you want `getInstance(2)` and `getInstance(5)` to return different objects, on the other hand, you're not using the Singleton pattern, you're using the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are not using a singleton. Notice that if you do the following (assuming that the Singleton.getInstance was actually static):

```
Singleton obj1 = Singleton.getInstance(3);
Singleton obj2 = Singleton.getInstance(4);
```

Then the obj2.x's values is 3, not 4.  If you need to do this, make it a plain class. If the number of values is small and fixed, you can consider using an `enum`. If you are having problem with excessive object generation (which is usually not the case), then you can consider caching values (and check sources or get help with that, as it is obvious how to build caches without the danger of memory leaks).

You also might want to [read this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/co-single.html) as singletons can be very easily overused.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason Singletons are an anti-pattern is that if written according to recommendations, with private constructor, they are very hard to subclass and configure to use in certain unit tests.  Would be required in maintaining legacy code, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't we do something like this:

```
public class Singleton {

    private int x;

    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() {}

    /**
     * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
     * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
     */
    private static class SingletonHolder { 
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(int x) {
        Singleton instance = SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
        instance.x = x;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a singleton, but may be something that could fix your problem.

```
public class KamilManager {

  private static KamilManager sharedInstance;

  /**
   * This method cannot be called before calling KamilManager constructor or else
   * it will bomb out.
   * @return
   */
  public static KamilManager getInstanceAfterInitialized() {
    if(sharedInstance == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("You must instantiate KamilManager once, before calling this method");

    return sharedInstance;
}

  public KamilManager(Context context, KamilConfig KamilConfig) {
    //Set whatever you need to set here then call:
  s  haredInstance = this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm scared to post this as an answer, but I don't understand why nobody think about this, maybe this answer was also given already I just didn't understand it.

```java
public class example  {
    private volatile static example instance;

    private String string;
    private int iInt = -1; //any number you know you don't want to use here

  private example() {

    //In case someone uses the private method to create a new Instance
    if (instance != null){
      throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
    }
  }

  public synchronized static example getIsntance(){
    if(instance == null){
      instance = new example();
    }
    return instance;
  }

public void methodDoingWork(){
    if(checkInit()){
      //DoSome
    }
  }

  private boolean checkInit(){
    boolean filled = (this.string != null) && (this.iInt != -1);
    return filled;
  }

  public void setString(String string) {
    if(this.string == null){
      this.string = string;
    }else{
      throw new RuntimeException("You try to override an already setValue"); 
    }
  }

  public void setiInt(int iInt) {
    if(this.iInt == -1){
      this.iInt = iInt;
    }else{
      throw new RuntimeException("You try to override an already setValue");
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `getInstance()` returns the same Instance everytime, I think this could work.
If this is wrong to much I will delete it, I'm just interested in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the problem as "how to make singleton with state", then it is not necessary to pass the state as constructor parameter.  I agree with the posts that initialize the states or using set method after getting the singleton instance.

Another question is: is it good to have singleton with state?

Answer (score 0):

In spite of what some may assert, here is a singleton with parameters in constructor

```java
public class Singleton {

    private static String aParameterStored;

    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton("Param to set");

    private Singleton() {
        // do nothing
    }

    private Singleton(String param) {
        aParameterStored = param;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    /*
     * ... stuff you would like the singleton do
     */
}
```

The singleton pattern say :

- ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists
- provide global access to that instance.

which are respected with this example.

Why not directly set the property ? It's textbook case to show how we can get a singleton having constructor with parameter but it could be useful in some situations. For example in inheritance cases to force the singleton to set some superclass properties.

Answer (score 0):

Something to add, in case if want that the parameters should only be initialized once and must not be overwritten then just implement a check and throw exception if somebody tries to initialized them again. Ex.:

```
public class Service {

private String host = null;
private String port = null;

private Service() {
}

private static class ServiceSingletonHolder {

    private static final Service INSTANCE = new Service();
}

public static Service getInstance() {
    return ServiceSingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
}

public void initilize(String host, String port) {
    if (this.host != null && host != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("host can not be overwritten");
    }

    if (this.port != null && port != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("port can not be overwritten");
    }

    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a common problem. Separating the "initialization" of the singleton from the "get" of the singleton might work (this example uses a variation of double checked locking).

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static volatile MySingleton INSTANCE;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
    public static void initialize(
            final SomeDependency someDependency) {

        MySingleton result = INSTANCE;

        if (result != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The singleton has already "
                    + "been initialized.");
        }

        synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
            result = INSTANCE;

            if (result == null) {
                INSTANCE = result = new MySingleton(someDependency);
            } 
        }
    }

    public static MySingleton get() {
        MySingleton  result = INSTANCE;

        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The singleton has not been "
                    + "initialized. You must call initialize(...) before "
                    + "calling get()");
        }

       return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Could always return "result" in the initialize method as well I suppose.

Answer (score -3):

Singletons are generally considered to be [anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and shouldn't be used. They do not make code easy to test.

A singleton with an argument makes no sense anyway - what would happen if you wrote:

```
Singleton s = SingletonHolder.getInstance(1);
Singleton t = SingletonHolder.getInstance(2); //should probably throw IllegalStateException
```

Your singleton is also **not thread-safe** as multiple threads can make simultaneous calls to `getInstance` resulting in more than one instance being created (possibly with different values of `x`).

Comment: Yes it is debatable; hence my use of the word "generally". I think it is fair to say that they are generally considered a bad idea

Comment: It is debatable - some people claim that what are called "anti-patterns" fit the definition of patterns, it's just that they are bad patterns.

Comment: I understand that they are bad.  I am doing distributed computing and need to share an object among multiple tasks.  Rather than deterministically initializing a static variable, I would like to abstract the logic into a Singleton.  I imagine I could make getInstance synchronized.  Would this work?  What I need to do is load a file once for many tasks, and only after the first task has been sent.  (I don't want my data serialized.)  I thought I would make my AbstractFileReader an argument to the getInstance method in order to make the Singleton more flexible.  I value your input.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what "distributed" means? There are other ways of achieving what you want: have you considered dependency injection? Or JNDI?

Comment: If you want to instantiate a number of file readers and reuse them, why not just use a Map<String,AbstractFileReader>, keyed on filename? You instantiate them as you need them and store them in the map (with proper synchronisation or using the java.util.concurrent maps).

Comment: @oxbow_lakes I adore your devotion to the question and I think the downvoter did not read your answer in relation to the question. Everything here is true in relation to the question! But i downvote because it is a anti-pattern under specific circumstances. Please relativize your answer and ill upvote.

Answer (score -3):

Singleton is, of course, an "anti-pattern" (assuming a definition of a static with variable state).

If you want a fixed set of immutable value objects, then enums are the way to go. For a large, possibly open-ended set of values, you can use a Repository of some form - usually based on a `Map` implementation. Of course, when you are dealing with statics be careful with threading (either synchronise sufficiently widely or use a `ConcurrentMap` either checking that another thread hasn't beaten you or use some form of futures).

Comment: Only an anti-pattern if used incorrectly, though that is the definition of an anti-pattern. Just because you have seen them where they didn't belong in the past does not mean that they do not have a place.

Comment: The correct use of a singleton is to demonstrate incompetent code.