# Singleton and Builder(Joshua's way)

Tags: java, builder

I am building a builder based on Joshua's builder pattern. my question is how can I make it singleton?
to elaborate my point, if I have the below builder

```
public class Widget {
    public static class Builder {
        private String name;

        public Builder( String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Widget build() {
            Widget result = new Widget(this);
            return result;
        }
        public Builder model( String value ) {
            this.model = value;
            return this;
        }
    }

    private final String name;

    private Widget( Builder b ) {
        this.name = b.name;
    }

    // ... etc. ...
}
```

I would call this builder from another class like
new Widget.Builder().name("abc").build()........

but what if I want only one instance of this Widget or I have a need to access this Widget from multiple places without resorting to creating a new one every time. Ideally I would like to confine the instantiation with in the Widget class. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, Singleton and Builder Patterns don't seem to go together: why would you need a builder if there is only one instance to build?

If what you need is to reuse a Builder object because you want to build a similar object several times, you can simply keep a reference to that Builder and use it as many times as you want (since you made it static):

```
Widget.Builder builder = new Widget.Builder("abc").model("def");
```

Then you can create several Widgets:

```
Widget w1 = builder.build();
Widget w2 = builder.build();
...
```

Comment: The reason I opted for builder was because this object has like 20 fields to set and instead of passing them all in constructor I prefer the builder way and the reason I need singleton is because these fields are config data that doesn't change very often.

Comment: @Java If [you really need a singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton) and I mean [that you really need one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?lq=1), then this would not apply.

Comment: @Java you have edited your question to clarify that you want a Widget singleton. That seems to confirm that it may not be the best way going forward. You might want to read [this post about configurable singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050991/singleton-with-arguments-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a Singleton, Joshua also has advice on [the best way to make a singleton in modern Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this, and want to avoid polluting your builder pattern then add a singleton to hold a centralized instance of the builder.

```
public enum CentralWidgitBuilder{
  INSTANCE; //Effective Java singleton technique

  private final Widget.Builder mBuilder = new Widget.Builder();

  public Widget.Builder getBuilder(){
    return mBuilder;
  }
}
```

Then to reference from anywhere:

```
CentralWidgitBuilder.INSTANCE.getBuilder().
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one builder object so you can use singleton pattern like this:

```
public class Widget {
public static class Builder {
    private static Builder builder;
    private String name;

    public Builder getInstance(String name){
       if (instance==null){
         instance=new Builder(name);
       }
       return instance;
    }

    private Builder( String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Widget build() {
        Widget result = new Widget(this);
        return result;
    }
    public Builder model( String value ) {
        this.model = value;
        return this;
    }
}

private final String name;

private Widget( Builder b ) {
    this.name = b.name;
}

// ... etc. ...
}
```

If you have multiple builders you may need a static Map in this class

Comment: yeah makes sense. thanks a lot but what If I want Widget to be singleton?

Comment: Then put the static instance to the widget class and pass the a builder to the getinstance method