# Creating java singleton with static inner class

Tags: java, android, singleton

I want to use the following pattern to create a singleton in java

```
public class Singleton {
        // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
        private Singleton() { }

        /**
        * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
        * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
        */
        private static class SingletonHolder { 
                public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

But what happens when the private constructor I want to call is

```
 private Singleton(Object stuff) {... }
```

How do I pass `stuff` to `INSTANCE = new Singleton()`? As in `INSTANCE = new Singleton(stuff);`

Rewriting the above snippet:

```
public class Singleton {
        // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
        private Singleton(Object stuff) { ... }

        /**
        * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
        * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
        */
        private static class SingletonHolder { 
                public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance(Object stuff) {
                return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;//where is my stuff passed in?
        }
}
```

EDIT:

for those of you claiming this pattern is not thread safe, read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh.

The object I am passing in is the android application context.

Comment: Why do you think you need a singleton in your application?

Comment: Your description is probably a sign that you should not use a singleton. In particular, what happens if you call: `Singleton.getInstance(object1); Singleton.getInstance(object2);`??? Do you now have two instances of your singleton? Do you mutate the first instance? etc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if you want to make a point make it. I am not going to write a dissertation on why I need a singleton.

Comment: Neither of these patterns look threadsafe.

Comment: Are you trying to create a factory ?

Comment: My question is about trying to understand the real problem that you're surely *trying to solve* with a singleton.

Comment: A singleton doesn't make sense if it depends on some parameter coming from outside the class.

Comment: you should have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)..you are making it way too complicated

Comment: @GriffeyDog it could conceivably be startup configuration or state information that needs to be available to the singleton.

Comment: @Anirudh his code sample is one of the ones listed on that page ;)

Comment: @mcfinnigan Perhaps, but this design leads to calling for the "singleton" with potentially different parameters, like in assylias's comment.

Comment: @GriffeyDog which leads to the point assylias and me are wondering: why to use a singleton for this? But we won't know if OP doesn't explain the real problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree 100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singleton with Arguments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050991/singleton-with-arguments-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

If you really want a singleton, there should be only one instance of it (duh!). If you add a parameter to `getInstance` you probably expect the returned instance to be different (otherwise there is no need for a parameter) which defeats the purpose.

If your goal is to add some configuration when the only instance is created, the simplest way would be to have your singleton query for the configuration information when it is instantiated:

```
public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton(getConfiguration());
```

where getConfiguration returns what is needed (whether by reading a file or forwarding some other variable for example).

---

**Usual disclaimer: [Singletons are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).**
Additional resource: [Google guide to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf) (in case you were not convinced the first time).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Singleton {
        private static Singleton singleton;

        // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
        private Singleton() { }

        public void addStuff(Object stuff){}    

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                 if(singleton == null) singleton = new Singleton()
                 return singleton;
        }
}
```

and use it as:

```
 Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
 s.addStuff(stuff);
```

or an alternative

```
public class Singleton {
        private static Singleton singleton;

        // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
        private Singleton() { }

        public static void redefine(Object stuff){

             singleton = new Singleton(stuff) // choose constructor based on parameters
        }


        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                 return singleton;
        }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this. But I was wondering about a more inclusive approach.

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe this is want you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read

[a singleton with parameters is not a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050991/singleton-with-arguments-in-java?rq=1)

The first answer argues why a >>singleton with parameters<< is not a singleton, and doesn't come near a singleton.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, but thanks for the Q/A.

Answer (score -1):

Why not get rid of SingletonHolder use factory pattern. You will have to decide what to do, when try to call getInstance twice, but with different 'stuff'.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton
    private final Object stuff;

    private Singleton(Object stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(Object stuff) {
         if (singleton == null) {
             singleton = new Singleton(stuff);
             return singleton;
         }

         return singleton; // or throw error because trying to re-init
   }
}
```

Comment: 'or throw error because trying to re-init' This defeats the purpose of a singleton

Comment: Agreed but going with the flow of the question. I would probably not use params in a singleton

Comment: @assylias What have I missed regarding thread safety? I can't spot it. CHeers

Comment: @AyubMalik The first version was not synchronized. Now it is fine.

Comment: However, the problem with this approach is if getInstance() gets called so many times in a large system, the overhead for synchronization is high. You could synchronize on the actual object.