# Specific instance/Non Singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, single-instance

How to **instantiate** java class with parameters and use the same instance through out the application?

What i want to do is when a tibco esb requests a web service call to my application,i will capture user information(user name) in one pojo class so that I can use this pojo class and user information at other places in application also for this particular tibco request.

This question might sounds crazy but I would like to implement something like this in my application.Waiting for your thoughts guys.

Comment: Is it a single-threaded application or a multi-thread app?

Comment: single-threaded application

Comment: How is this *not* a singleton?

Comment: As per my  understanding singleton classes or pattern should not have a parameterized constructor.If it has parameterized constructor then its not a singleton.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050991/singleton-with-arguments-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ThreadLocal solution:

```
public class MyClassInstanceHolder {
    private static ThreadLocal<MyClass> instance = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static setInstance(MyClass instance) {
        instance.set(instance);
    }
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        instance.get();
    }
}
...
MyClass myInstance = MyClassInstanceHolder.getInstance();
```

So in that thread you'll have access to the object stored in that ThreadLocal.

Comment: For the above solution,should i need to call or depend upon OtherClass everytime?I mean if i like to use MyClass instance in some other class then i would need to instantiate OtherClass also(WebServiceImpl class in my case)?

Comment: Well, not, it's only an example I've done fast. You could have two static methods, one for set another for get, so you don't need to instantiate the class. I'm going to update the example.