# Can a spring ldap repository project access two different ldap directories?

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to create a spring rest application to return values that may come from two different LDAP directory servers.  Is this possible using spring LDAP repositories?  Is it possible to create more than one `ldaptemplate` and `contextsource` so I can query both directories?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure separate `ldapTemplate` and `contextSource` beans for each LDAP directory.

You can refer to the following basic configuration (JavaConfig);

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "com.foo.ldap1.repositories", ldapTemplateRef="ldapTemplate1")
public class Ldap1Configuration {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource1() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap1.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap1.base"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap1.user"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap1.password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="ldapTemplate1")
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate1() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource1());        
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "com.foo.ldap2.repositories", ldapTemplateRef="ldapTemplate2")
public class Ldap2Configuration {
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource2() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap2.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap2.base"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap2.user"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap2.password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="ldapTemplate2")
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate2() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource2());        
    }

}
```

Then you can refer to each instance in your application as per following;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ldapTemplate1")
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate1;
```

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ldapTemplate2")
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate2;
```

Side note; If the number of LDAP directories increases then it will be better to implement a `ldaptemplate` factory which takes connection details and returns `ldaptemplate` instances ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051043/4511854)).

Comment: I had tried this but couldn't figure out how I would connect each ldapTemplate to an ldap repository.  I am using the @EnableRepositories annotation on my LdapConfiguration class.  I need to have different ldap repository classes for my different ldap directories.

Comment: You can set the `ldapTemplateRef` property of `@EnableLdapRepositories` in order to configure the name of the `ldaptemplate` bean to be used. In your case, you should configure separate configuration classes having separate @EnableLdapRepositories annotation for your LDAP directories.