# How to inject a parameter into a singleton class?

Tags: java, servlets, design-patterns, servletcontextlistener

I have a singleton class which has been adopted so that the super method requires now an additional parameter, in my example it is set to foobar.

```
public class MySingleton extends MySystemLoader       
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6053739985096001185L;
private static MySingleton SINGLETON = new MySingleton();

public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    return SINGLETON;
}

private MySingleton() {
    super( MySingleton.class, "foobar" );
}

}
```

My problem how can I inject this parameter to the this singleton class. 
The previous version of the private constructor looked like this

```
private MySingleton() {
     super( MySingleton.class );
}
```

To be more concrete my app will run on a tomcat server and I want to inject the context name of my application into this singleton, because this will extract some configuration properties with this name and such stuff. Would be a context listener the right choice but also then how can i inject the context name into the singleton?

Comment: `MySingleton` does not have a superclass (other than `Object`), how can you call `super` with any parameters at all?

Comment: You have a static instance of your singleton but want to pass a dynamic parameter (context name) to it? Somehow singleton seems to be a very poor choice here. The only ways I can imagine is some kind of setter which assigns context name to a field of the singleto instance.

Comment: You need to add a new attribute in MySingleton class and create the constructor method with this parameter

Comment: Thanks for the answers I switched from Singleton to a Factory Implementation, with this I could solve my Problem. This SO was also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050991/singleton-with-arguments-in-java/1051043#1051043