# Help me remove a Singleton: looking for an alternative

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Background: I have some classes implementing a subject/observer design pattern that I've made thread-safe. A `subject` will notify it's `observers` by a simple method call `observer->Notified( this )` if the `observer` was constructed in the same thread as the notification is being made. But if the `observer` was constructed in a different thread, then the notification will be posted onto a `queue` to be processed later by the thread that constructed the `observer` and then the simple method call can be made when the notification event is processed.

So… I have a map associating threads and queues which gets updated when threads and queues are constructed and destroyed. This map itself uses a mutex to protect multi-threaded access to it.

The map is a singleton.

I've been guilty of using singletons in the past because "there will be only one in this application", and believe me - I have paid my penance!

One part of me can't help thinking that there really will be only one queue/thread map in an application. The other voice says that singletons are not good and you should avoid them.

I like the idea of removing the singleton and being able to stub it for my unit tests. Trouble is, I'm having a hard time trying to think of a good alternative solution.

The "usual" solution which has worked in the past is to pass in a pointer to the object to use instead of referencing the singleton. I think that would be tricky in this case, since observers and subjects are 10-a-penny in my application and it would very awkward to have to pass a queue/thread map object into the constructor of every single observer.

What I appreciate is that I may well have only one map in my application, but it shouldn't be in the bowels of the subject and observer class code where that decision is made.

Maybe this is a valid singleton, but I'd also appreciate any ideas on how I could remove it.

Thanks.

PS. I have read [What's Alternative to Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton) and [this article](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/where-have-all-singletons-gone.html) mentioned in the accepted answer. I can't help thinking that the ApplicationFactory it just yet another singleton by another name. I really don't see the advantage.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid singletons?  They most certainly have their place.  Every idiom can be misused and abused.  But an application-wide map of thread->notification_queue seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Mordachai: I understand singletons have their place and it may well be that this queue/thread map is perfectly valid. It only started to bug me when I was writing some unit tests and it just felt awkward having the singleton there.

Comment: What thread library are you using?

Comment: @outis: we have our own thread API

Comment: Can your threads store thread-specific data that's accessible to other threads? Like NSThread's `-threadDictionary`?

Comment: @Mordachai: A plain global would work just fine. It doesn't have to be a singleton. And even better, the map could be passed to every thread at startup. I can't recall ever seeing a case where singletons "have their place".

Comment: @outis: this is a Win32 app, Window's equivalent is Thread Local Storage. That's an interesting idea - leave it to the OS to do the thread/queue mapping via TLS. As long as I can say 'get the queue for thread x' not necessarily just the current thread.

Comment: People mostly say use Dependency Injections or create the object once and pass it down as member variables.

Answer (score 3):

If the only purpose to trying to get rid of the singleton is from a unit test perspective, maybe replacing the singleton getter with something that you can swap in a stub for.

```
class QueueThreadMapBase
{
   //virtual functions
};

class QeueueThreadMap : public QueueThreadMapBase
{
   //your real implementation
};

class QeueueThreadMapTestStub : public QueueThreadMapBase
{
   //your test implementation
};

static QueueThreadMapBase* pGlobalInstance = new QeueueThreadMap;

QueueThreadMapBase* getInstance()
{
   return pGlobalInstance;
}

void setInstance(QueueThreadMapBase* pNew)
{
   pGlobalInstance = pNew
}
```

Then in your test just swap out the queue/thread map implementation. At the very least this exposes the singleton a little more.

Comment: Ah... interesting. In fact, I have already have split out some other singletons in this way for testing so I can just reuse the Base part locally, and ignore the singleton part, but I didn't go as far adding the `setInstance` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts towards a solution:

Why do you need to enqueue notifications for observers that were created on a different thread? My preferred design would be to have the `subject` just notify the observers directly, and put the onus on the observers to implement themselves thread-safely, with the knowledge that `Notified()` might be called at any time from another thread. The observers know which parts of their state need to be protected with locks, and they can handle that better than the `subject` or the `queue`.

Assuming that you really have a good reason for keeping the `queue`, why not make it an instance? Just do `queue = new Queue()` somewhere in `main`, and then pass around that reference. There may only every be one, but you can still treat that as an instance and not a global static.

Comment: Personally, when I write multithreaded observers, I prefer that my observers methods always be called in the context of their own thread.  Having another thread inject itself sounds only useful for cases where the obeservation activity is very, very lite.

Comment: @JS Bangs: I can see what you're saying regarding thread-safety, but the current implementation is to have the subjects deal with mutexes and thread-safety rather than the observers. Changing that now would not go down too well with the team! (Incidentally, it's the queue-thread map that is the singleton; not a queue - there are many queues and threads; one map). What would worry me are the changes required to have to pass around this reference to the map object to every single observer instance.

Comment: @Mordacahai: yes, this is the approach I've taken - each observer's Notified() method runs in the context of it's owning thread. There are mechanisms to force an asynchronous notification (queued) (in the single threaded case) or force a synchronous notification (method call) (in the multi-threaded case) but they are rarely used and are for 'advanced' use if you are aware of the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with putting the queue inside the subject class? What do you need the map for?

You already have a thread reading from the singleton queue map. Instead of doing that simply make the map inside the subject class and provide two methods to subscribe an observer:

```
class Subject
{
  // Assume is threadsafe and all
  private QueueMap queue;
  void Subscribe(NotifyCallback, ThreadId)
  {
     // If it was created from another thread add to the map
     if (ThreadId != This.ThreadId)
       queue[ThreadId].Add(NotifyCallback);
  }

  public NotifyCallBack GetNext()
  {
     return queue[CallerThread.Id].Pop;
  }
}
```

Now any thread can call the GetNext method to start dispatching... of course it is all overly simplified, but it's just the idea.

**Note:** I'm working with the assumption that you already have an architecture around this model so that you already have a bunch of Observers, one or more subjects and that the threads already go to the map to do the notifications. This gets rid of the singleton but I'd suggest you notify from the same thread and let the observers handle concurrency issues.

Comment: There is one queue per thread. There can be many observers constructed in one thread. Also, many subjects can notify from the same thread, so having one queue per subject is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Your observers may be cheap, but they depend on the notification-queue-thread map, right?

What's awkward about making that dependency explicit and taking control of it?

As for the application factory Miško Hevery describes in his article, the biggest advantages are that 1) the factory approach doesn't hide dependencies and 2) the single instances you depend on aren't globally available such that any other object can meddle with their state. So using this approach, in any given top-level application context, you know exactly what's using your map. With a globally accessible singleton, any class you use might be doing unsavory things with or to the map.

Comment: The intent was (is) that the queue/thread mechanism is transparent to the users of observers - all a derived observer needs to know is that the Notified() method is not necessarily a synchronous method call if threading is involved. The observer base class may well depend on the map and a notification queue, but I don't want to (if I can help it) drag that dependency into derived classes and force each derived observer to know about the queue/thread map. There are lots (>500) of observers in my app! (I assume that's what you mean by "taking control of it"?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I meant! I don't mean to wear your patience out or preach to the choir here, since you've already indicated you don't like singletons either - but the transparency of singletons is only illusory. That is, it's only transparent until it fails. Having said that, maybe JS Bangs' idea is more agreeable if you've got 500 derived observer classes (yikes).

Comment: @Jeff: that's not necessarily over 500 observers per subject :-) There are many observers and many subjects, in various degrees of many-to-many relationships

Comment: Fair enough - would it be more manageable if you centralize observer creation in a factory? (If you're not already doing so! :) )

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to have the observers provide a queue when they registered with the subject; the observer's owner would be responsible for both the thread and the associated queue, and the subject would associate the observer with the queue, with no need for a central registry.

Thread-safe observers could register without a queue, and be called directly by the subject.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I think this exposes too many dependencies. One of the benefits of hiding the queue behaviour from derived observers and subjects is that it becomes very easy to move observers between threads (in source code; not runtime) and have them 'automatically' know which queue to use; the users of the observers and subjects don't have to worry about that implementation detail.

Comment: In that case, a singleton is probably what you want. There's no conceptual problem with this, since by definition there is only one "set of all threads in the process". Alternatively (but less portably) you could put the queue in thread-local storage if your platform has such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a Reset method that returns a singleton to its initial state that you can call between tests? That might be simpler than a stub. It might be possible to add a generic Reset method to a Singleton template (deletes the internal singleton pimpl and resets the pointer). This could even include a registry of all singletons with a master ResetAll method to reset all of them!

Comment: That's something worth thinking about. I might combine that with the "plug-in" singleton idea by Snazzer. Cheers.