# Getting parts classes from product design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have problem with designing parts in my game library. I have more parts in separated classes (for example Matchmaking, Scheduler, Auth, EventProcessor,...).

There will be ONE instance used at runtime (There's no need for two Schedulers or Matchmaking classes). I have seen multiple ways of accessing theese classes.

*In following text ProductName is the name of library and PartName is the name of class.*

- First way was by class called **ProductName** and it had static methods like **ProductName.getPartName()**, then the calls were **ProductName.getPartName().call()**.
- The second one was done by using *singleton pattern* (**PartName.getInstance()**), the calls were **PartName.getInstance().call()**.
- And the third one was by having all methods in class marked as static, so the calls were **PartName.call()**

What is the best way / best design for this?

Thanks for answers!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to have one and one only instance of a class in your project, you will probably need to apply the [Singleton Software Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). With this, there will always be just one instance of the Singleton in your project. This code is an example of Singleton, with test included:

ClassicSingleton.java:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

SingletonTestCase.java:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class SingletonTest extends TestCase {
   private ClassicSingleton sone = null, stwo = null;
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
   public SingletonTest(String name) {
      super(name);
   }
   public void setUp() {
      logger.info("getting singleton...");
      sone = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
      logger.info("...got singleton: " + sone);
      logger.info("getting singleton...");
      stwo = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
      logger.info("...got singleton: " + stwo);
   }
   public void testUnique() {
      logger.info("checking singletons for equality");
      Assert.assertEquals(true, sone == stwo);
   }
}
```

Results:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
init:
     [echo] Build 20030414 (14-04-2003 03:08)
compile:
run-test-text:
     [java] .INFO main: getting singleton...
     [java] INFO main: created singleton: Singleton@e86f41
     [java] INFO main: ...got singleton: Singleton@e86f41
     [java] INFO main: getting singleton...
     [java] INFO main: ...got singleton: Singleton@e86f41
     [java] INFO main: checking singletons for equality
     [java] Time: 0.032
     [java] OK (1 test)
```

As you can see in the results, the two Singletons used are giving the same memory reference; `Singleton@e86f41`. Therefore, they are the same object, which is the desired behaviour.

Hope it helps,

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: Besides, if you want to study alternatives to the Singleton Design Pattern, you might find the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton) useful.