# swift singleton with parameters

Tags: swift

I'm relatively new to swift and searched around but could not find any satisfactory answer to my problem. I would like to have a Singleton class instance which can be initialized with some variables. E.g.

```
public class Singleton {
   var car: String
   var bus: String

   init(car: String, bus: String) {
    self.car = car
    self.car = bus
   }

   func drive() {
       print("I will drive")
   }
}


public class SingletonConsumer {
  // create an instance of Singleton Once
  var driver: Singleton = Singleton(car: "honda", bus: "volvo")
  driver.drive()
}



public class driverClassWorld : SingletonConsumer {
   driver.drive()
}
```

how can i achieve it? I tried protocol but issue i am hitting is how to instantiate singleton class with parameters.

Comment: This is a regular class. Why do you call it a singleton? In a realistic case, where would `"honda"` and `"volvo"` come from?

Comment: Try to make your variable immutable static - static let driver: Singleton = Singleton(car: "honda", bus: "volvo")

Comment: `car`/`bus` are poor examples for a singleton. I'd bet if you look deeper you won't be able to find a valid example for tor this kind of singletons, which is a good indicator that you don't need this in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singleton and init with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429544/singleton-and-init-with-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this problem?

First remove singleton from your brain for a moment. Because I think you have the wrong idea on what a singleton is.

Now lets rephrase your question to: "How to instantiate a class with parameter"

Its like this:

```
import Foundation

class Test {

    let someText : String!

    init(something:String){
        someText = something
    }

    func test(){
        print("TEST \(someText)")
    }
}

let a = Test(something: "Me")
a.test()
```

Output:

```
TEST Optional("Me")
```

You just need to define a init with the parameters you want.

Now to properly instantiate a singleton (basically it just the class above but single instance). There are a lot of ways, the old Objective C approach is still valid.

But for swift this is the most common pattern. You need to define a Static Property.

Example:

```
import Foundation

class Test {

    static let shared = Test(something: "REAL SINGLETON")

    let someText : String!

    init(something:String){
        someText = something
    }

    func test(){
        print("TEST \(someText)")
    }
}

Test.shared.test()
```

Output:

```
TEST Optional("REAL SINGLETON")
```

Now reread the definition of a singleton:

> a singleton class is a class that can have only one object (an
>   instance of the class) at a time

For other patterns in declaring a singleton:

https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift

**Now, you might wonder: When does this singleton instance instantiated?**

> Answer: It is when it is first used/called.