# Singleton SharedInstance Function Called Twice

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, singleton, nstimer

All singleton functions are twice calls.
The "Prova" function, and the selector of the timer are twice calls.

```
class Timer {
    static let sharedInstanceTimer = Timer()
    var TimerCounter : NSTimer = NSTimer()
    var Counter : Int = Int()
    var TimerGameOver : Int = Int()
    var TimerBonusMultipleCircle : Int = Int()
    var TimerBonusBigCircle : Int = Int()
    var TimerCounterInterval : NSTimeInterval = 1

    init()
    {
        self.Counter = 60
        self.TimerGameOver = 10
        self.TimerBonusMultipleCircle = 5
        self.TimerBonusBigCircle = 5
        self.TimerCounterInterval = 1
    }
    func StartTimerCounter()
    {
        self.TimerCounter = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.TimerCounterInterval, target: Game.sharedInstanceGame, selector: #selector(Game.sharedInstanceGame.UpdateAllCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func StopTimerCounter()
    {
        self.TimerCounter.invalidate()
    }
}
```

And... In another file I call `StartTimerCounter()`

```
import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    static let sharedInstanceFirstViewController = FirstViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "00:00:60", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        Circle.sharedInstanceCircle.CreateCircle()
        view.layer.addSublayer(Circle.sharedInstanceCircle.PrincipalCircle)
        Game.sharedInstanceGame.Play()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func ReturnToMenu()
    {
       navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Leaving aside the various errors that I corrected as suggested below I have tried several solutions but I can not find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Tested this and it´s only called once. Show the code you´re using to call the Timer class and i´ll figure out why it´s been calling twice.

Comment: done and waiting for your response

Comment: You have way too many singletons. Singletons are not an alternative to keeping a object reference in a property. In particular, a singleton for a view controller doesn't make any sense. From what I can see from your code, none of the classes should be a singleton.

Comment: Ok but why is called twice?

Comment: The code you added to your question still doesn't show a call to `startTimerCounter`

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Your `sharedInstanceTimer` is instantiating `Timer` (which is, itself, a `NSTimer`). It should not subclass `NSTimer`.
2. You then initialize `TimerCounter` to a second timer which you never use.
3. The above will instantiate two timers. You then have `StartTimerCounter` that instantiates another `NSTimer` every time you call it. Assuming you want only one timer, you should should have `StartTimerCounter` invalidate any prior timer before starting a new one.
4. I'd call this class `TimerManager`, or something like that, to avoid clashes with Swift 3 type, `Timer`.
5. Method names should start with lowercase letters, as should properties. In the spirit of the Swift 3 API guidelines, you might want to shorten the method names, too.
6. Also, if you're going to define a singleton, I'd declare a `private init()` initializer, to prevent other classes from accidentally ever instantiating another `TimerManager` object.

So, that yields something like:

```
class TimerManager {
    static let shared = TimerManager()

    private var timer: NSTimer?   // this certainly should be private

    // whether you make these private or not, or constants vs properties, is up to you

    private var tounter : Int = 60
    private var timerGameOver : Int = 10
    private var timerBonusMultipleCircle : Int = 5
    private var timerBonusBigCircle : Int = 5
    private var timerCounterInterval : NSTimeInterval = 1

    // make sure no one else accidentally instantiates another TimerManager

    private init() {
    }

    /// Start timer.

    func startTimer() {
        stopTimer()    // cancel prior timer, if any

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timerCounterInterval, target: Game.sharedInstanceGame, selector: #selector(Game.sharedInstanceGame.updateAllCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        Game.sharedInstanceGame.prova()
    }

    /// Stop timer.

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

---

An unrelated, deeper observation here: I'd suggest that you keep the timer object loosely coupled with respect to the `Game` object. So, I'd excise all "game" related stuff from this class:

```
class TimerManager {
    static let shared = TimerManager()

    private var timer: NSTimer?   // this certainly should be private
    private var timerHandler: (() -> ())?

    // whether you make these private or not, or constants vs properties, is up to you

    private var timerCounterInterval: NSTimeInterval = 1

    // make sure no one else accidentally instantiates another TimerManager

    private init() {
    }

    /// Start timer.
    ///
    /// - parameter timerHandler: The closure that will be called once per second.

    func startTimer(timerHandler: () -> ()) {
        stopTimer()    // cancel prior timer, if any

        self.timerHandler = timerHandler
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timerCounterInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        timerHandler?()
    }

    /// Stop timer.

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timerHandler = nil
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Then, when the `Game` object wants to start a timer, it might do:

```
TimerManager.shared.startTimer {
    self.updateAllCounter()
}
prova()
```

Now, perhaps you simplified your timer object for the purpose of this question and perhaps there's more that's needed in this `TimerManager` object (as suggested by all these other properties that aren't otherwise referenced in your code snippet), but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea: The `TimerManager` shouldn't be involved in the business of calling any specific `Game` methods or the like. It should simply provide a mechanism by which the caller can simply supply a block of code that the timer should periodically invoke.

Comment: I would also ask why this class is a singleton?  Given that it now (correctly) has a delegation pattern, it makes my spidey sense tingle; delegates and singletons mean the potential for delegate-wars. This should probably be a simple class that can be instantiated as required with appropriate arguments to `init`. If the `Game` only ever creates one instance, so be it, but that doesn't mean they should use a singleton

Comment: I agree. IMHO, the same is true with `Game`, itself. But I thought I may have already packed too much in this answer.

Comment: Yes. And I just saw from their edit that they have a view controller singleton too!

Comment: The truth is that I do not understand very well the use of the singleton and am looking to gain experience but continues to call him twice even with the solutions proposed here.

Comment: Singletons are intoxicatingly simple to use, but introduce all sorts of subtle issues. It's admittedly a matter of debate (which is discouraged here on Stack Overflow), but I might refer you to [What is so bad about singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975) and [What's alternative to singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655). Singletons can be useful in generic utilities, such as logging mechanisms or the like, but should generally be avoided for reasons that increasingly manifest themselves in larger projects.

Comment: If you say "I only need one right now" that is a bad reason to have a singleton. "There should be only one ever" is a much better reason. And singleton with a delegate that isn't a singleton is weird.

Comment: And even if you will have "only one ever", it doesn't necessarily mean that it is a good candidate for a singleton. IMHO, none of these (neither the `FirstViewController`, the `Game`, nor this timer manager) should be singletons.