# Implementing a class of only one instance

Tags: java, android, singleton, instance

Good day everybody! Here's my question:

I need to make a Tutorial for my app. For doing this, I've created a class called TutorialClass which contains some methods that I need to call from several other classes. The working flow is quite like this:

**Class 1:**

```
//...
if(Tutorial.tutorialStep==Tutorial.TUTORIAL_STEP1){
    Tutorial.TutorialStep1();
    Tutorial.tutorialStep=Tutorial.TUTORIAL_STEP2;
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
//...
if(Tutorial.tutorialStep==Tutorial.TUTORIAL_STEP2){
    Tutorial.TutorialStep2();
    Tutorial.tutorialStep=Tutorial.TUTORIAL_STEP3;
}
```

And so on...
**All the classes I use, have not to extend Activity necessarily**

You can find this piece of code in several class I use. 
So, first of all I need to create an instance of TutorialClass

```
TutorialClass Tutorial = null;
```

So here is the question: how can I use this instance from all the classes in which I have to show my tutorial? As you can see, **the value of *tutorialStep* has to be visible from all classes, and all classes have to see that value or change it**, in order to let the tutorial go on.

Here is the code of my tutorial class:

```
public class TutorialClass{

    Context context;
    public static int tutorialStep;

    final int TUTORIAL_STEP1=1;
    final int TUTORIAL_STEP2=2;
    final int TUTORIAL_STEP3=3;
    //...

    TutorialClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Tutorial1() { ... }
    public void Tutorial2() { ... }
    public void Tutorial3() { ... }
    //...

}
```

I've read that exist a Singleton class that allows to reach my objective, but I've noticed that it's not the best solution. Do you have any solution? Thanks to all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list . Choose the one you want. You'll probably end up with `Singleton`.

Comment: What are your arguments against using Singleton pattern? Why is it "not the best solution"?

Comment: I've never used Singleton classe because I've never needed it. So I was just looking for a solution to this problem and I end up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create another class that return instance of the `TutorialClass`

```
public class TutorielInstance {
    private static TutorialClass instance;
    private static Context context;

    public static synchronized TutorialClass getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance=new TutorialClass(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public  static  void setContext(Context c){
        context=c;
    }
}
```

and then in the activity you can use

```
TutorielInstance.setContext(this);
TutorialClass tutorialClass=TutorielInstance.getInstance();
```