# What is a singleton, in plain English?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I've been Googling for about an hour now and I still don't have a clear idea of what a singleton is. Can anyone make it a bit clearer to me and perhaps post a code example?

All I know is that you can only have one instance of a given class. But can't you just then use a static class for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check wiki and reference  links given on wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern

Comment: if a class has only one object (instance), this one is called a "singleton". you may come to the idea to force that there is only one object but this is where the evil starts.

Comment: In plain English, Singletons are the worst idea ever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yeah.. I know.. I'm a simpleton.. So what's a Singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726685/yeah-i-know-im-a-simpleton-so-whats-a-singleton)

Comment: @FredOverflow - I think you're overstating it. There are worse ideas than Singletons. Most of the tactics used in World War I, for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple plain English<sup>1</sup> version is: *Singleton Class is a Class that has, and can only have, only one instance*.

> But can't you just then use a static class for that?

No.  That's not what a "static" class is in Java.  In Java "static" classes can have multiple instances just like any other class.

The `static` keyword is used (for classes) to mean that the instance of a nested class is not tied to a specific instance of the enclosing class.  And that means that expressions in the nested class cannot refer to instance variables declared in the enclosing class.

Prior to Java 1.5 (aka Java 5), there was no support for the singleton design pattern in Java.  You just implemented them in plain Java; e.g.

```
    /** There is only one singer and he knows only one song */
    public class Singer {
        private static Singer theSinger = new Singer();
        private String song = "I'm just a singer";

        private Singer() { 
            /* to prevent instantiation */
        }

        public static Singer getSinger() { 
            return theSinger; 
        }

        public String getSong() {
            return song;
        }
    }
```

Java 1.5 introduced the `enum` types which can be used to implement singletons, etc.

```
    /** There are two Singers ... no more and no less */
    public enum Singer {
        DUANE("This is my song"),
        RUPERT("I am a singing bear");
        
        private String song;

        Singer(String song) {
            this.song = song;
        }
        
        public String getSong() {
            return song;
        }
    }
```

---

<sup>1 - Of course, you need to understand what "class" and "instance" mean.  Since the Programming / IT English meanings of these words is different to the "plain English" meanings, it is a stretch to call this a "plain English" description.  On the other hand, if the reader doesn't *already* understand what "class" and "instance" mean, they don't have the base knowledge needed to understand the "singleton" idea, or see the point of it.</sup>

Comment: +1: at last somebody addressed the simplest answer in plain English.

Comment: Your code examples made everything crystal clear to me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

singleton is a class with a private constructor and you could only get one instance of it. for further explanation why this coding style is done I suggest you read the chapter regarding singletons in this book

http://www.wowebook.com/book/head-first-design-patterns/

Chapter 5 is all about singleton

Answer (score 0):

> The singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the
>   instantiation of a class to one object.
>
> Note the distinction between a simple static instance of a class and a
>   singleton: although a singleton can be implemented as a static
>   instance, it can also be lazily constructed, requiring no memory or
>   resources until needed. Another notable difference is that static
>   member classes cannot implement an interface, unless that interface is
>   simply a marker. So if the class has to realize a contract expressed
>   by an interface, it really has to be a singleton.

All from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)