# How to make class to create and store string once that is used multiple times?

Tags: java

I have a connection with a Docker Client. The problem is that it runs 2 times per second (it's a thread). It's inefficient to build the same connection every time.

I want to run this function to build the string once and store it in a variable and just return the variable every time it is needed rather than rebuilding the same string over and over. How can I do it?

```
 public class Docker {

    public static DockerClient dockerClient() {

    DockerClient dockerClient;

    try {

        Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
        DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                .withDockerHost("tcp://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort())
                .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker/config.json")
                .build();

        dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

        return dockerClient;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: `DockerClient x = Docker.dockerClient();`...?

Comment: You've only shown us the `dockerClient` function; if you're asking how to refactor your code that calls the `dockerClient` function repeatedly, because you want to make it only call the `dockerClient` function once, then please show us the code that calls `dockerClient` repeatedly so we can help you fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726685/yeah-i-know-im-a-simpleton-so-whats-a-singleton

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern:

- make your `dockerClient` method private;
- add a private static `DockerClient` field;
- add a public static `getClient` method that will return the DockerClient field if not null or call your dockerClient method to create it if field is null;

  ```
  public class Docker {

      private static DockerClient INSTANCE;

      public static DockerClient getClient() {
          if (INSTANCE == null) {
              INSTANCE = dockerClient();
          }

          return INSTANCE;
      }

      private static DockerClient dockerClient() {
          // YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
      }
  }
  ```

Thus your `dockerClient` method will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
private static DockerClient dockerClient;
static {

  try {
    Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
    DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
            .withDockerHost("tcp://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort())
            .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker/config.json")
            .build();

    dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static DockerClient dockerClient() {
    return dockerClient;
}
```