# Singleton or Global Function?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, global

I was under the impression that singleton is the proper design pattern which adds the flexibility for the design to evolve, extend, etc. , where globals are just a workaround. But in a question asked in this forum I was told try to avoid singleton pattern and go for global non-member functions. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Let me [link to the post again](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference page:　[Global vs Singleton in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504036/global-vs-singleton-in-net)

In my understanding, with singleton, I can control when the object is initialized. But with globals, it's a little difficult to do it.